# Facebook Ads API (Marketing API) Insights - no "Clicks (All)"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Ads API (also called the Marketing API), specifically the /insights edge on campaign nodes like: [campaign-id]/insights

I am using graph v2.5 of the API.

The Facebook Ads UI has a "Clicks (All)" column - a very important metric. However, I can't find a field in the insights API corresponding to "Clicks (All)", nor can I find other fields that total into this metric.

Anyone know what field(s) I should be using?

Comment: try this ...https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/quickstart

Comment: Have you looked at the calls and responses the UI is making to the API? the UI uses the same API to generate its reports (though, is likely using 2.4)

Comment: @Igy great idea.

It looks like they are actually using 2.3.
They are also using a deprecated endpoint: /adcampaign-groups
And yes, they are using a field unavailable in 2.5: "clicks".

Frustrating.

Comment: @Igy - Looks like /adcampaign-groups was actually renamed to /campaigns, which is what I was trying to use. But yeah, the "clicks" field works in 2.3 and 2.4 and gives the number that appears in the UI. "clicks" is unavailable in 2.5. I can't find anything in the documentation about that so I'm going to file a bug.

Comment: No, that's not a bug, it's in the changelog from 2.4 to 2.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official Ads Manager UI does not use the latest version of the Graph API (v2.5). It uses v2.3.

According to this bug report:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/909624365795625/
clicks has been deprecated. Applications that want to mimic the Ads Manager UI should just use whatever version of the API it is using.

In this case, v2.4 would work. "clicks" still exists in that version.

Also - this was documented in the changelog:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_5_deprecations
See 90-day deprecations > Marketing API > Insights

Comment: In the changelog for v2.5 it says to use inline_link_clicks instead of clicks... but those fields have different values - and I haven't found any combination of other fields that add up to "Clicks (All)".

Comment: Also, I'm not able to call v2.4 - either in the Graph API Explorer or from the .NET SDK.  When I try from code, it gives OAuthException #2635 - "You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version."